# JQuery Mobile #Home link reload page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have an internal link in my jquery mobile code:

```
<a href="#home" data-role="button">Start Again</a>
```

The problem is it's not actually restarting to page when I link back to it.

Anyone know a way to do this?

UPDATE: I am using Ajax to navigate the pages and as I have hashes in the url it's not returning to the start url (minus the hashes) so I cannot get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `data-ajax="false"` to the `<a>` tag. This will force jQuery to do a full reload.

Comment: This is awesome but not working for getJSON call. Kindly update.